# How to get data from current input

Tags: jquery

Hello i have two input with datalist and how to get current input value when i press Post button

```
<datalist id="OrganizationsList">
        <option id="Id" value="value" />
</datalist>


 <div class="form-group" id="Resolutions">
                        <label for="orgId" class="form-control-label">Организации:</label>
                        <input list="OrganizationsList" class="form-control" id="orgId" name="orgId">
                        <<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Post</button>
                    </div>

 <div class="form-group" id="Resolutions">
                        <label for="orgId" class="form-control-label">Организации:</label>
                        <input list="OrganizationsList" class="form-control" id="orgId" name="orgId">
                        <<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Post</button>
                    </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What obstacles are you encountering?

Comment: when i try var opt = $("#organization option[value='" + $('#orgId').val() + "']").attr('id'); get first value

Comment: What have you tried? By the way, your html is invalid  you have repeated `id` values (they should be unique)

Comment: Add what you tried to the question, along with what happened when you tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

also your input ID must be unique , change them or swap ID to Class

```js
$('button').click(function(){
let input = $(this).closest('div').find('input[name="orgId"]').val()
alert(input)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<datalist id="OrganizationsList">
        <option id="Id" value="value" />
</datalist>


 <div class="form-group" id="Resolutions">
                        <label for="orgId" class="form-control-label">Организации:</label>
                        <input list="OrganizationsList" class="form-control" id="orgId" name="orgId">
                        <<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Post</button>
                    </div>

 <div class="form-group" id="Resolutions">
                        <label for="orgId" class="form-control-label">Организации:</label>
                        <input list="OrganizationsList" class="form-control" id="orgId" name="orgId">
                        <<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Post</button>
                    </div>
```

Comment: thank you!  don’t know html and javascript you helped me out

Comment: @RamazanovAdilbek  no problem if this is what you looking for accept my post as correct answer

Comment: how i can to do default value by id="Id" ?

Comment: i know how to by value but i get from backend data {Id : "Id", Name : "Name"} and put in datalist

Comment: @RamazanovAdilbek you can do Ids like id="orgId-1", id="orgId-2", id="orgId-3", id="orgId-4" ......

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
extract($_POST);
echo $orgId;
echo $orgId2;

 ?> 
  <form action="" method="post">
  <datalist id="OrganizationsList">
        <option id="Id" value="value" />
</datalist>


 <div class="form-group" id="Resolutions">
                        <label for="orgId" class="form-control-label">Организации:</label>
                        <input list="OrganizationsList" class="form-control" id="orgId" name="orgId">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Post</button>
                    </div>

 <div class="form-group" id="Resolutions">
                        <label for="orgId" class="form-control-label">Организации:</label>
                        <input list="OrganizationsList" class="form-control" id="orgId" name="orgId2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Post</button>
                    </div>
             </form>
```